# Deny - Create Subsites

Tags: sharepoint-server, permissions

The DENY appear for all the users in the "Owner group", tried everything still cant remove, please help.... i cant create subsites due to this,.....

[image: show Deny]

[image: User permission for web application]

[image]
[image]
[image]

here is the log:

System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED)), StackTrace:    at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb.CreateWeb(String strWebUrl, String strTitle, String strDescription, UInt32 nLCID, String strWebTemplate, Boolean bCreateUniqueSubweb, Boolean bConvertIfThere, Guid appInstanceId)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb.SPWebCollectionProvider.CreateWeb(String strWebUrl, String strTitle, String strDescription, UInt32 nLCID, String strWebTemplate, Boolean bCreateUniqueSubweb, Boolean bConvertIfThere, Guid appInstanceId)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWebCollection.Add(String strWebUrl, String strTitle, String strDescription, UInt32 nLCID, String strWebTemplate, Boolean useUniquePermissions, Boolean bConvertIfThere, Guid appInstanceId)     at Micro... 27721aa0-d216-40e2-277c-234542d06ef0
01/26/2022 13:57:10.71* w3wp.exe (0x24F8)                           0x1E2C  SharePoint Foundation           General                         ai1wu   Medium      ...soft.SharePoint.SPWebCollection.Add(String strWebUrl, String strTitle, String strDescription, UInt32 nLCID, String strWebTemplate, Boolean useUniquePermissions, Boolean bConvertIfThere)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages.NewSubwebPage.BtnCreateSubweb_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)     at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)     at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument)     at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)     at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)     at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest()     at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)     at System.Web....  27721aa0-d216-40e2-277c-234542d06ef0
01/26/2022 13:57:10.71* w3wp.exe (0x24F8)                           0x1E2C  SharePoint Foundation           General                         ai1wu   Medium      ...HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()     at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step)     at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)     at System.Web.HttpApplication.PipelineStepManager.ResumeSteps(Exception error)     at System.Web.HttpApplication.BeginProcessRequestNotification(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb)     at System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context)     at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationHelper(IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)     at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotification(IntPtr ...  27721aa0-d216-40e2-277c-234542d06ef0
01/26/2022 13:57:10.71* w3wp.exe (0x24F8)                           0x1E2C  SharePoint Foundation           General                         ai1wu   Medium      ...rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)     at System.Web.Hosting.UnsafeIISMethods.MgdIndicateCompletion(IntPtr pHandler, RequestNotificationStatus& notificationStatus)     at System.Web.Hosting.UnsafeIISMethods.MgdIndicateCompletion(IntPtr pHandler, RequestNotificationStatus& notificationStatus)     at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationHelper(IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)     at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotification(IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)     27721aa0-d216-40e2-277c-234542d06ef0
01/26/2022 13:57:10.71  w3wp.exe (0x24F8)                           0x1E2C  SharePoint Foundation           General                         ftd0    Medium      Access Denied. Exception: Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED)), StackTrace:   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequestInternalClass.CreateWeb(String bstrUrl, String bstrTitle, String bstrDescription, UInt32 nLCID, Boolean bCreateUniqueWeb, Guid& pguidAppInstanceId, String bstrAppWebDomainId, Boolean bConvertIfThere, Guid& pgWebId, Guid& pgRootFolderId, Boolean bCreateSystemCatalogs)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.CreateWeb(String bstrUrl, String bstrTitle, String bstrDescription, UInt32 nLCID, Boolean bCreateUniqueWeb, Guid& pguidAppInstanceId, String bstrAppWebDomainId, Boolean bConvertIfThere, Guid& pgWebId, Guid& pgRootFolderId, Boolean bCreateSystemCatalogs).  27721aa0-d216-40e2-277c-234542d06ef0
01/26/2022 13:57:10.71  w3wp.exe (0x24F8)                           0x1E2C  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                      b4ly    High        Leaving Monitored Scope: (Creating SPWeb Product) Execution Time=8.4528; CPU Milliseconds=4; SQL Query Count=1; Parent=Request (POST:https://xxx/_layouts/15/newsbweb.aspx) 27721aa0-d216-40e2-277c-234542d06ef0

Comment: out of a sudden, another problem created while my site admin account can create subsite now:
https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/300180/access-denied-for-all-sites-collections-in-same-content-db-while-other-content-d

Answer (score 0):

From your question, it seems that subsite creation for all sites is disabled for all user.

Below are the steps to enable it.

1. In the left pane of the new **SharePoint admin center**, select
   Settings. At the bottom of the page, select **classic settings page**.
2. Under **Site Creation**, select to show or hide the **Create site** command.
   [image]

- If you choose Disable subsite creation for all sites it will also
  hide the subsite creation command (including classic) and disable
  users from being able to create new subsites through a URL or API.
- If you choose Enable subsite creation for classic sites only users
  will be able to create new subsites for classic sites.
- If you choose Enable subsite creation for all sites users will be
  able to create new subsites from any SharePoint site.

3. Select OK when you are done.

[Sub Site creation settings](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/sharepoint/manage-site-creation#manage-detailed-site-and-subsite-creation-settings-in-the-classic-sharepoint-admin-center)

Comment: i m using SharePoint Server 2016 on permise, cant see the setting tat u suggested

Answer (score 0):

From your description, you are using SharePoint server, right?

Please check to see if the problem occurs on other site collections.

You can also create a brand new site collection to compare the result.

Comment: yes, i m using SharePoint Server 2016 on permise, all site collections are same, all cant create subsites.

Comment: Do site collection administrators have the same problem?

Try to run PSconfig to repair SharePoint.

Comment: same for site collection admin, it is like all users..

Comment: Try creating a subsite using powershell, if this does not work, we suggest you open a ticket to Microsoft: https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2014/09/create-subsite-in-sharepoint-using-powershell.html

Comment: same to powershell... cant create with access denied error

Answer (score 0):

Try to look at *Central Administration - Application management - Manage web applications - `<YourWebApp>` - User Policy* and *Permission policy* options.

Comment: they are in my question screenshot my brother...

Comment: It's just not clear from your screenshot, what kind of policies web application has. I mean that window under User policy. You attached only "User permissions for Web application" and probably settings from one of "Permission policy levels".

Comment: can create subsite now, but another problem created
[link]https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/300180/access-denied-for-all-sites-collections-in-same-content-db-while-other-content-d